# How to cancel await SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, serial-port, task

My c# WinForms application reading asynchronously from serial port. It works, but when the port closes, an `StackOverflowException` appears. The Call Stack is overflowed with line `await ReadAsync(serialPort)` on the end of `ReadAsync`. My guess is the line await ReadAsync still run even though  I close SeriaPort, `keepReading` flag and checking `serialPort.IsOpen`. 
Hence the question, how to cancel await ReadAsync, is it possible? Appreciate some help here because I'm beginner.

```
public async Task ReadAsync(SerialPort serialPort)
    {

            if (serialPort.IsOpen && keepReading)
            {
                try
                {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                        await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
                        content += serialPort.Encoding.GetString(buffer);
                        //do sth with content
                        buffer = null;

                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                }
                if (keepReading && serialPort.IsOpen)
                    await ReadAsync(serialPort);
            }
    }
private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            keepReading = false;
            serialPort.Dispose();
            serialPort.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Open();
            keepReading = true;
            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                await ReadAsync(serialPort);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When does the failure occurs? Immediatly after closing the port? Because I have made a test and it does not give me the exception. May be it fails after a long period of being work?

Comment: I think an StackOverflowException could be thrown after a the application has been working for a while and this due to the recursive calling to ReadAsync. After all every time the apps receives info through the port a new call is put in the stack and the first call does not end, so after a while if you receive many many times info you could end up with so many calls to ReadAsync that an stackoverflowexception is thrown

Comment: @taquion Yes, at short intervals, the error doesn't occur. So how to replace recursive calling?

Comment: Create (or receive via parameter) a CancellationToken, register SerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer() on the token, pass it to SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync() and use the token to cancel the operation. Details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610437/3809520

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap `serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);` into another async method and use Task Cancellation to cancel this method before you close the serial port.
 [Cancel an Async Task or a List of Tasks (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674886.aspx)