# SerialPort BaseStream ReadAsync - CancellationToken never cancelled?

Tags: c#, serial-port, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource

I try to read data from serial port in async manner keeping in mind that operation must not take more time than a specified period. The code I use:

```
private async Task<int> Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reading response to buffer of size {0}, offset {1}, max to cnt {2}", buffer.Length, offset, length);

        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Begin reading...");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Re-entering read");

            int bytesRead = 0;

            using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 333))) // 333 ms
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for read to complete...");

                int tmpOffset = offset + totalBytesRead;
                int tmpLength = length - totalBytesRead;
                Console.WriteLine("tmpOffset: {0}, tmpLength: {1}", tmpOffset, tmpLength);

                try
                {
                    bytesRead = await mPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, tmpOffset, tmpLength, cts.Token);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception during read: {0}, stack trace: {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Read completed");
            }

            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            Console.WriteLine("Bytes read: {0}, totalBytesRead: {1}, buffer: {2}", bytesRead, totalBytesRead, BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Read finished");

        return totalBytesRead;
    }
```

And the following code returns these messages to the console:

```
Reading response to buffer of size 256, offset 0, max to cnt 256
Begin reading...
Re-entering read
Waiting for read to complete...
tmpOffset: 0, tmpLength: 256
Read completed
Bytes read: 1, totalBytesRead: 1, buffer: 52-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Re-entering read
Waiting for read to complete...
tmpOffset: 1, tmpLength: 255
Read completed
Bytes read: 8, totalBytesRead: 9, buffer: 52-45-4A-30-30-36-4A-44-52-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
Re-entering read
Waiting for read to complete...
tmpOffset: 9, tmpLength: 247
```

After the last message it hangs. Certainly longer than 333ms timeout which is (should) be used. For me it looks like the token is never cancelled or at least this cancellation is never captured. I am 99% sure that the device is not sending any more data so that's why I am counting on the timeout to fire. 
I am new to C# so maybe there is something I don't quite understand. Can you see any reason why the task is not being cancelled here?

I tried to replicate & adjust approach presented in [this](https://johnthiriet.com/cancel-asynchronous-operation-in-csharp/#cancel-with-a-timeout) article.

Answer (score 9):

I recently had the same issue, trying to communicate with some old embedded instrument talking over serial line. My solution is a set of extension methods that look like this, I don't dispose the whole port, closing the base stream seems enough, and then i reopen it immediately if at the time of cancellation it was open.

```
public static class SerialAsyncExtensions
{
    public static async Task<int> ReadSerialAsync(this SerialPort f_Serial, byte[] f_Buffer, int f_Offset, int f_Count, int f_Delay)
    {
        if (f_Delay > 0)
            await Task.Delay(f_Delay);

        return await f_Serial.BaseStream.ReadAsync(f_Buffer, f_Offset, f_Count);
    }

    public static async Task<int> ReadSerialAsync(this SerialPort f_Serial, byte[] f_Buffer, int f_Offset, int f_Count, int f_Delay, CancellationToken f_Token)
    {
        CancellationTokenRegistration l_Token_Registration = f_Token.Register((param) =>
        {
            SerialPort l_Serial = (SerialPort)param;

            l_Serial.DiscardInBuffer();

        }, f_Serial);

        if (f_Delay > 0)
            await Task.Delay(f_Delay, f_Token);

        try
        {
            int l_Result = await f_Serial.BaseStream.ReadAsync(f_Buffer, f_Offset, f_Count, f_Token);

            return l_Result;
        }
        catch(System.IO.IOException Ex)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException("ReadSerialAsync operation Cancelled.", Ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            l_Token_Registration.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static async Task WriteSerialAsync(this SerialPort f_Serial, byte[] f_Buffer, int f_Offset, int f_Count)
    {
        await f_Serial.BaseStream.WriteAsync(f_Buffer, f_Offset, f_Count);
    }

    public static async Task WriteSerialAsync(this SerialPort f_Serial, byte[] f_Buffer, int f_Offset, int f_Count, CancellationToken f_Token)
    {
        CancellationTokenRegistration l_Token_Registration = f_Token.Register((param) =>
        {
            SerialPort l_Serial = (SerialPort)param;

            l_Serial.DiscardOutBuffer();

        }, f_Serial);

        try
        {
            await f_Serial.BaseStream.WriteAsync(f_Buffer, f_Offset, f_Count, f_Token);
        }
        catch(System.IO.IOException Ex)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException("WriteSerialAsync operation Cancelled.", Ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            l_Token_Registration.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `DiscardInBuffer()` in the token registration as an alternative. This seems simpler since it does not appear to alter the port's open/closed state.

Comment: The problem is not the dirty buffer, the problem is the Serial port readasync hanging indefinitely, and the only way to unblock the readasync at that point is by closing the basestream

Comment: DiscardInBuffer definitely forces ReadAsync to return in my application. Have you tried it?

Comment: @AdamV.Steele I finally managed to try your suggestion and I must agree with you. It indeed returns from the read. I already updated my code to reflect your change.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. But didn't update the text.

Answer (score 4):

It is because of the [internal implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,f956b0c07e86df64) (line 417) of the ReadAsync method. Basically, there is a check on the cancellationToken right at the entry point of the method, but then it (the cancellationToken) is not passed forward to subsequent calls ("all the way"). So, if you are lucky to have cancelled right before your execution reaches the call to ReadAsync, you get the expected behaviour.

I am not going to debate on why they chose to not make it cancellable (on other posts, which i don't remember now, I read that it was a safety precaution, so to not leave the buffer in some funky state).

What you can do is to wrap the call with some sort of timer, or how it worked for me:

> cancellationToken.Register(() => mport.Dispose());

because what i wanted was to end things for good.

This caused me an

> IOException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

which i caught and handled (in my case, I threw an OperationCanceledException - but just for this IOException, not any).

There is even more nasty stuff about the SerialPort stream communication. Some other helpful things:
http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport