# How to Implement Continuous Read/Write with SerialPort in C# with Timeout Handling?

Tags: c#, async-await, serial-port, timeout, task

I'm working on a WPF application in C# on .NET 8.0 where I need to continuously read from and write to a serial port using the SerialPort class from the System.IO.Ports v8.0.0 NuGet package. I have specific serial port settings, and I'm sending a 16-byte data packet, then waiting to receive a 36-byte response or timing out. To clarify, this program is communicating with an embedded device where I am sending commands from the computer and awaiting status responses from the embedded device. However, if the data I send is corrupted during transmission or erroneous the embedded device may discard my command and will not send out a status response. Thus, I've been struggling to figure out how to work with timeouts for the read operation.

The serial port is configured as follows:

```cs
private void InitializeCommunication()
{
    try
    {
        _port = new()
        {
            PortName = _comPortName,
            BaudRate = 2_000_000,
            Parity = Parity.Odd,
            DataBits = 8,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            ReadTimeout = 100,
            WriteTimeout = 100
        };

        _port.Open();

        StartPeriodicCommunication();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _port.Close();
    }
}
```

The StartPeriodicCommunication method looks like this and essentially performs a write then read communication loop until an exception is thrown:

```cs
private async void StartPeriodicCommunication()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await SendReceiveRs485Data();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        NotificationQueue.Enqueue("Communication Error: " + ex.Message);
        _port.Close();
    }
}
```

The first method I tried for the read operation was to pass in a cancelation token to the SerialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync() method, but if the embedded device doesn't respond the program will get stuck indefinitely waiting for ReadAsync to return. Upon further investigation, it seems that after ReadAsync has reached a certain point in its execution it no longer checks the state of the cancellation token leading to it never returning unless an exception is thrown. The unsuccessful method I tried looked like this:

```cs
Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[36];
int numBytesRead = 0;

using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new(100);

while (numBytesRead < buffer.Length && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    int bytesRead = await _port!.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer.Slice(numBytesRead), cts.Token);
    numBytesRead += bytesRead;

    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException($"Received {numBytesRead} bytes");
    }
}
```

So as an alternative to this, I have devised two methods for implementing the read operation with a timeout:

1. **Closing the Port:** The first method involves closing the SerialPort if the read operation doesn't complete within the timeout period. This approach seems to work, but I'm concerned about the potential impact on performance and resource management due to frequently opening and closing the port. I know that this is not the ideal approach as the SerialPort can take an undetermined amount of time to re-open after closing, but my idea behind this approach was to find a way to get ReadAsync to return with an exception.

```cs
Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[36];
int numBytesRead = 0;

using CancellationTokenSource cts = new(100);
cts.Token.Register(() => _port.Close());

try
{
    while (numBytesRead < buffer.Length && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int bytesRead = await _port!.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer.Slice(numBytesRead), cts.Token);
        numBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    NotificationQueue.Enqueue($"Read Timeout: {ex.Message}");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    _port.Open();
}
```

2. **Using Task.WhenAny():** The second method uses Task.WhenAny() with a Task.Delay to implement the timeout. This method doesn't require closing and reopening the port, but I'm unsure if the unfinished ReadAsync tasks might lead to memory leaks or other issues.

```cs
Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[36];
int numBytesRead = 0;

using CancellationTokenSource cts = new(100);

while (numBytesRead < buffer.Length && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var readTask = _port!.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer.Slice(numBytesRead), cts.Token);
    var delayTask = Task.Delay(100);

    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(readTask, delayTask);
    if (completedTask == readTask)
    {
        int bytesRead = readTask;
        numBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException($"Read Timeout: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

These are simplified code examples to help get my point across so hopefully they don't contain mistakes or ambiguities, but I'm looking for advice on which method is more appropriate for a production environment, considering resource management, performance, and reliability. Are there potential pitfalls with either approach that I should be aware of? It seems like working with the SerialPort class has always been painful based on the posts I have seen on here and from Ben Voigt so if there's a better way to handle this pattern in C#, I'm open to suggestions.

Edit #1:
I have come up with a 3rd method that seems to work well. If I hit my timeout and discard the input buffer it seems to make ReadAsync() return. Unless there is a problem with this approach, I think this meets my needs. However, I'm still open to better approaches. I'm a little new to async tasks so I'm not sure how to ensure a task gets terminated and has all its resources released.

```cs
Memory<byte> buffer = new byte[36];
int numBytesRead = 0;

using CancellationTokenSource cts = new(100);
cts.Token.Register(() => _port.DiscardInBuffer());

try
{
    while (numBytesRead < buffer.Length && !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int bytesRead = await _port!.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer.Slice(numBytesRead), cts.Token);
        numBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    NotificationQueue.Enqueue($"Read Timeout: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: The idea of closing the port is really bad. As I see it, you first have to determine if you can use a syscall to fetch bytes from the system buffer (e.g. a **read()**) that can timeout (e.g. Python has this capability). If there is such a syscall, the problem is resolved. Otherwise consider having a thread to perform the read. A parent thread can wait for an event from this read thread or a timeout event. There's no need to try to abort/terminate the read syscall because it can remain active in its own thread.

Comment: @sawdust Closing and opening the port is definitely not the way I want to handle this, but I suppose I'm not sure when ReadAsync stops if I use method 2 or if there is a better way to try and cancel my await. I mostly want to ensure that if I leave the method that calls await ReadAsync() that the task will stop or be garbage collected.

Comment: So are you reporting that there's no syscall that can timeout? I know nothing about C#, but there's no need to use any "*async*" (i.e. non-blocking mode) method. The read thread can use a blocking syscall; you don't want to poll the system buffer for data. There's no need to terminate such a syscall in a child thread. After the parent thread detects a timeout, you can continue to use the read thread to fetch the next response. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489038/linux-c-c-why-use-blocking-or-non-blocking-read-over-serial-usb/77492038#77492038

Comment: @sawdust this seems to be the thread everyone references when talking about the C# SerialPort class: https://sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

The main issue I'm facing is that ReadAsync only checks the cancelation token when it enters the method, but doesn't pass it into the deeper calls. There was some discussion on it in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917749/c-sharp-serialport-basestream-readasync-cancellationtoken-never-cancelled

Comment: If you really want to control the timing in detail, it would be best not to implement it using the C# API. You can create a dedicated process in C++ and leave most of the processing to it. It would be better for C# programs to specialize in receiving and processing the resulting data.

Comment: @kunif I have considered doing this in the past, but I'm less familiar with C++, but if it gives me more control over monitoring the status of the USB serial port device and performing read/writes, I may have to look into it more.

Comment: Isn't it an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? You should check whether packets are really being corrupted or insufficient data is being generated due to noise, etc., and take countermeasures. It could be a hardware countermeasure, or it could just be resending the command. Also, like sawdust's comment, the timeout itself is a normal occurrence and there should be no need to Close/Re-Open the port. Regardless of the timeout, if you check that the received data is in the correct format and range of possible values, you can detect and remove corrupted packets.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable source linking in Visual Studios debug options, you'll be able to step into that code. I don't think there's a way on Windows to time out.

If you want to enforce a timeout, on .NET 8.0 you can use [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync).

Comment: It should be clarified that the `WaitAsync` enforces a timeout on the waiting, not on the operation itself. After the timeout exception is thrown, the operation will keep running in the background in a fire-and-forget fashion.

Comment: Is there any way to terminate a call to ReadAsync? Or wrap the call to ReadAsync in a Task that I could ensure is cancellable? My main concern is that when ReadAsync hangs that I can release that task as well as all the resources it was utilizing. Because in the event where the device is unreachable for X amount of time I would like to prevent creating hundreds of ReadAsync tasks that are hanging indefinitely.

Comment: @Fishayyy [there is no generic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540260/stopping-a-task-without-a-cancellationtoken/77313824#77313824 "Stopping a task without a CancellationToken") to cancel non-cancelable operations.